# Use updateMenu to change color or marker Ploty px.scatter_matrix

Tags: python, button, plotly

I am plotting a scatter matrix using px.scatter_matrix: i want to use an update menu to change the color or marker, so that i can highlight a different aspects.

this is my attempt, but not working so far:

```py
import plotly.express as px

#list of symbols for button 1
Symbols_marker_1 = {
   'setosa': "circle", 
              'versicolor': "diamond", 
              'virginica': "circle",
    
}

#list of symbols for button 2
Symbols_marker_2 = {
   
              'setosa': "square", 
              'versicolor': "triangle", 
              'virginica': "trianlge",
    
}


#Button to change symbols
buttons = [dict(method='restyle',
                 label='symbol_map_change',
                 visible=True,
                 args=[{'label': 'symbol_map_change',
                       'symbol_map':Symbols_marker_1,
                       }
                     ]),
          dict(method='restyle',
                 label='symbol_map_change_2',
                 visible=True,
                 args=[{'label': 'symbol_map_change',
                       'symbol_map':Symbols_marker_2,
                       }
                     ])        
          
          ]


um = [{'buttons':buttons,
         #set button position 
       'direction': 'down',
        "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 10},
        "showactive":True,
        "x": -0.4,
        "xanchor": "left",
        "y": 0.9, 
        "yanchor": "top"}
       ]



#example modified from https://plotly.com/python/splom/
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
   dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
   symbol="species", symbol_map= Symbols_marker_1, 
   color="species", 
   title="Scatter matrix of iris data set",
   labels={col:col.replace('_', ' ') for col in df.columns}) # remove underscore
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)
fig.show()
```

If this ins't possible with my current method, is there a way of producing the desired effect?

Comment: Do you want to change the marker for *all* observations?

Comment: @vestland Yes!  For example a button that changes from markers being related to "species" to one related to "sepal_width" (althout a cateogrical value)

Comment: In my real dataset i want a button that allows to group by values in one columA (attribute A) or colulmB(attributeB)- to better display relations.

Comment: This isn't very easy using only `px`. Could I interest you with an approach that uses `Plotly Dash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really looking to *change the marker*, but rather change the underlying data that the markers represent, since:

> In my real dataset i want a button that allows to group by values in
> one columA (attribute A) or colulmB(attributeB)- to better display
> relations

And this can quickly become very painful following your setup. But it's both easy and elegant using Plotly Dash. So if you can use that instead, you should. The following setup lets you switch between two figures where the first is the original where the data is represented by `df['species']`. The second figure shows the same data, but for a different category defined in the column df['AttributeB'], and is a random choice between three fictional categories `['science', 'fiction', 'flowers']`

#### Dropdown selection = Species

[image]

#### Dropdown selection = AttributeB

[image]

#### Complete code for JupyterDash

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# data
df = px.data.iris()

# synthetic data for AttributeB
df['AttributeB'] = [random.choice(['science', 'fiction', 'flowers']) for obs in df['species']]

fig1 = px.scatter_matrix(df,
                         dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
                         color="species")

fig2 = px.scatter_matrix(df,
                         dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
                         color="AttributeB")

app = JupyterDash(__name__)
options = ['species', 'AttributeB']

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='plot'),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='variables',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in options],
                value=options[0]
            )
        ])
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('variables', 'value')])

def update_graph(fig_name):

    if fig_name == 'species':
        return fig1

    if fig_name == 'AttributeB':
        return fig2

app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8070, dev_tools_ui=True,
          dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: I've just run the code on GoogleColab, Indeed this works! I have some doubts about using Dash due to its usability: My initial approach has been to download all images as html, so i can embed them in an offline html document (with plotly libraries in separate folder). With this method i can show the presentation to non python users without a problem as the document alwasy opens.

Comment: However since I've had issues embedding Scatter matrix and Parallel coordinates into the html file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598736/plotly-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-key-of-undefined-at-htmlcanvas) I could switch. Is it possible to create a Plotly Dashboard that opens as realiably and easily as an Html file with plotlyhtml embedded? To get widespread adoption of this new way of presenting in my deparment it is more necessary to have realiable presentations than extra functionality.

Comment: @David8 `Is it possible to create a Plotly Dashboard that opens as realiably and easily as an Html file?`. ***Sure!*** `with plotlyhtml embedded?` ***Not sure***. But I would say that the felxibility and vast opportunities  you'll get with Dash is well worth the effort to give it a serious try.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start looking into Dash then see if i can present using that.